# Search for inline style in entire document and replace color

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles

I have a document with many inline styles. I would like to search for `color: #019e93;` and replace the color with `#80D5CF`. How can I do that?

Comment: This is an [X/Y question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The way to solve this is to change your code to not use inline styling, but external CSS files instead. Then you can change the colour in a single place.

Comment: I have a complete WordPress site, and not able to remove all of the wp generated inline styles and replace with external css files. I only want to change a color with some sort of jQuery script what searhces the whole document and replace `color1` to `color2` where it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Attribute selector `[]`

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[style*='#019e93']").forEach(el => {
  el.style.color = "red"; // Or use "#80D5CF"
})
```

```html
<div style="font-size:1rem; color: #019e93;">TEST</div>
```